# IF statement with VLOOKUP formula return different result when the VLOOKUP result is zero in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calculation

While calculate IF statement with VLOOKUP formula return different result while perform logic test with empty string in IF statement .Please refer the below calculation

D1 cell formula calculation:
Calculate VLOOKUP formula in D1 cell if the lookup value match and return the second column value as 0(zero).

D2 cell formula calculation:
Calculate IF statement with VLOOKUP formula, while perform logical test VLOOKUP result is 0(zero) and compare the value with empty string its return True. Normally 0=” “ return False in Ms Excel(Refer D4 cell calculation)

D3 cell formula calculation
Calculate IF statement with VLOOKUP formula, while perform logical test refer the D1 cell(D1 cell having VLOOKUP formula and return zero) and compare the value with empty string(D1=” “ ) its return False.

```
Example

A1=1  B1=11
A2=2  B2=   (empty string)
A3=3  B3=33
A4=4  B4=44
A5=5  B5=55

D1 cell value

**Formula** : =VLOOKUP(2,A1:B5,2)     
**Result**=0

D2 cell value

**Formula** : =IF(VLOOKUP(2,A1:B5,2)="",TRUE,FALSE)   
**Result**= “  “(empty string)

D3 cell value 

**Formula** : =IF(D1="",TRUE,FALSE)    
**Result**=0

D4 cell value

**Formula** : =0="“ 
**Result**=False
```

Please refer below image

[image]

Can anyone help to resolve this case

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formulas/vlookup-if-blank-return-blank ?